# Unable to set up Spring boot in Intellij

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, intellij-idea

I am trying to use Spring Initializer and create a basic Spring boot project. Able to do it fine on home PC. But when it comes to work PC, it doesn't work. I can't use Spring Initialzer directly from Intellij. There are no options to choose, I just end up with a blank screen as follows:

[image]

I tried going directly to https://start.spring.io/ and download a spring boot setup. When I open the project, the dependencies seems to download instantly (clearly not the case). But none of the the Spring related stuff found under the External Libraries portion. The dependencies are clearly not getting downloaded.

I have added proxy settings under the HTTP Proxy option and the connection is tested working.

[image]

Also to note I have other Spring projects on my work laptop which are working fine. Only this new project simply not pulling the dependencies. Can I get some help on what could be the reason. Checked on other colleague laptops and theirs does this fine. Unable to find settings on their laptop which is different from mine. Please help. Thank you.

The following is the error output for reference.

[image]

Comment: How did you open the new project? By importing it? If so, how?

Comment: Blank window is not normal. Is there anything suspicious in [idea.log](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207241085-Locating-IDE-log-files)? You may file an issue at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/IDEA with screenshots describing your steps and idea.log file attached.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build the project from command line or GIT Bash using mvn clean install command,in the project directory. If Maven is not installed, please try to do the same and try building the project.

Please post the stack trace if you find, when the build fails.

At the same time ensure that dependencies are present in your local .m2 directory. If the added dependencies are not found in your local,this should be some issue with your proxy.

Couldn't help you more as we don't have any stack trace or error present.

You might some useful information here,please have a look https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/spring-boot.html